# ffmpeg H265 to H264 colors are off?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am wanting to convert a H265 video to H264 with as little to no quality loss possible. However, when converting the output colors are off with most noticeably the reds become orange. In general the output video colors are duller/saturated/grayer.

I believe [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32383/ffmpeg-vf-scale-shifts-colors-to-washed-out) question is relevant, so is it possible to add color_range, color_space, color_transfer and color_primaries flags to a file without reencoding the entire thing again?

command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 17 output.mp4
```

input video stream:

```
{
  "index": 0,
  "codec_name": "hevc",
  "codec_long_name": "H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)",
  "profile": "Main 10",
  "codec_type": "video",
  "codec_time_base": "1/24",
  "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
  "codec_tag": "0x0000",
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
  "coded_width": 1920,
  "coded_height": 1080,
  "closed_captions": 0,
  "has_b_frames": 2,
  "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
  "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
  "pix_fmt": "yuv420p10le",
  "level": 120,
  "color_range": "tv",
  "color_space": "bt2020nc",
  "color_transfer": "smpte2084",
  "color_primaries": "bt2020",
  "refs": 1,
  "r_frame_rate": "24/1",
  "avg_frame_rate": "24/1",
  "time_base": "1/1000",
  "start_pts": 0,
  "start_time": "0.000000",
  "disposition": {
    "default": 1,
    "dub": 0,
    "original": 0,
    "comment": 0,
    "lyrics": 0,
    "karaoke": 0,
    "forced": 0,
    "hearing_impaired": 0,
    "visual_impaired": 0,
    "clean_effects": 0,
    "attached_pic": 0,
    "timed_thumbnails": 0
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "eng",
    "BPS": "4421595",
    "DURATION": "00:41:46.417000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_FRAMES": "60154",
    "NUMBER_OF_BYTES": "1385295394",
    "_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP": "mkvmerge v62.0.0 ('Apollo') 64-bit",
    "_STATISTICS_TAGS": "BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES"
  }
}
```

output video stream:

```
{
  "index": 0,
  "codec_name": "h264",
  "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
  "profile": "High 10",
  "codec_type": "video",
  "codec_time_base": "1/48",
  "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
  "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
  "coded_width": 1920,
  "coded_height": 1088,
  "closed_captions": 0,
  "has_b_frames": 2,
  "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
  "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
  "pix_fmt": "yuv420p10le",
  "level": 40,
  "chroma_location": "left",
  "refs": 1,
  "is_avc": "true",
  "nal_length_size": "4",
  "r_frame_rate": "24/1",
  "avg_frame_rate": "24/1",
  "time_base": "1/12288",
  "start_pts": 0,
  "start_time": "0.000000",
  "duration_ts": 30798848,
  "duration": "2506.416667",
  "bit_rate": "4073900",
  "bits_per_raw_sample": "10",
  "nb_frames": "60154",
  "disposition": {
    "default": 1,
    "dub": 0,
    "original": 0,
    "comment": 0,
    "lyrics": 0,
    "karaoke": 0,
    "forced": 0,
    "hearing_impaired": 0,
    "visual_impaired": 0,
    "clean_effects": 0,
    "attached_pic": 0,
    "timed_thumbnails": 0
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "eng",
    "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
  }
}
```

Comment: Had a similar issue sometime back. TAL at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66240097/6200672, might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this metadata may also be signaled in the bitstream, but you can do a remux (copies video bits, doesn't re-encode) on the video and set the mp4 container metadata with a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -c:v copy -color_primaries bt2020 -color_range tv -colorspace bt2020nc -color_trc smpte2084 output_updated.mp4
```

This is set to match your input video settings.

[reference FFMPEG docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Codec-Options) (search for `color_trc` to get to the right part)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way (and maybe more consistent since it is more 'direct') to edit h264/h265 video stream metadata (formally called 'VUI') is to use the bitstream filters.

e.g. in your case: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=colour_primaries=9:transfer_characteristics=16:matrix_coefficients=9 out.mp4`

You MUST use integers as arguments to the bsf, the table of integers and their respective names can be found in [Recommendation ITU-T H.273](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.273).